# Solving System of Equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra, finite-difference-method

I want to solve a huge system of equations which is generated using the **Finite-Difference-Method**. The Problem with that system is that it is badly conditioned and so `NSolve` is not able to find solutions.

There are already some posts dealing with that kind of problem:

[Badly conditioned matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19699/badly-conditioned-matrix-generalluc)

[Solving using LinearSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34576/is-linearsolve-the-most-robust-way-to-solve-the-equation-ax-b/34582#34582)

[Solving a linear system with a badly conditioned matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144540/solving-a-linear-system-with-a-badly-conditioned-matrix)

Sadly non of that posts can actually help me with my Problem. Because of the size of the system calculating the condition number takes a lot of time and so I'm not able to "prove" that the system is badly conditioned. The final question would be if somebody know a way to solve that equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are this equations linear ? If so you can try to transform  the equations.

If you have a nearly linear dependent basis for your equations, it may help, first to search for a new orthogonalized basis, write the equation in this basis and then solve the equations.

As an example we solve a 3D problem: Given a not orthogonal badly conditioned basis: bas and a vector v, we are searching coefficients: coef, so that coef.bas == v:

```
b1 = {1., 0, 0}; b2 = {1., 1. 10^-12, 0}; b3 = {1, 0, 1. 10^-12};
bas = {b1, b2, b3};
 v = a + 10^12 b + 10^12 c;
coef = {c1, c2, c3};
sol = Solve[coef.bas == v , coef][[1]];
Print["error= ", (coef /. sol).bas - v]
(*error= {1.08677*10^20,-1.90735*10^-6,0.}*)
```

This results in an error message: "General::luc: Result for `1` of badly conditioned matrix `2` may contain significant numerical errors." and trimendous errors.

On the other nad, if we first calculate a better, orthogonal basis, we obtain:

```
newbas = Orthogonalize[bas];
sol = Solve[coef.newbas == v, coef][[1]];
Print["Error= ", (coef /. sol).newbas - v];
(*Error= {0.,0.,0.}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel.
For the last 2 days I thought about the Problem and how to solve it or how to describe it better so others could understand it. 
The conclusion was that I don't have  enough knowledge to fully understand the underlaying Problem and ho to describe it so there will be plenty more days of lerning ahead. 

For your Question: Yes the equations are linear.